# Spellchecking highlighting problem in TexStudio when writing in Arabic

Tags: texstudio, arabic, spelling, right-to-left

When I write a document in Arabic it behaves differently than in English when it comes to highlighting words misspelled. Consider the screenshot below:

1. Arabic comma *right* after the target word, though *correctly spelled*, was red underlined
2. Arabic comma one space after the target word, though output not accepted, was correct
3. English comma *right* after the target word, was correct
4. When no comma, everything is fine
5. When the target word was misspelled, was red underlined as expected

Obviously, the first case is a bug that needs to be fixed, meaning that every occurrence followed by an Arabic comma would usually invoke a misspelling error and highlighting which is rather problematic.
It seems to be that the editor does not regard the Arabic comma `،`(pointing upwards usually) as an English comma`,` but as a part of the preceding word, which leads to all this mess.

**Is there any fix for that?**

**Note:**
TeXstudio 2.7.0 (hg 4307+:7e7903c73aac+)

**Update**
A ticket was opened in TexStudio to fix this bug:
`#702 Spellchecking in Arabic does not regard the Arabic comma as a comma`

**Copy & Paste**
`هنا كتابة النص باللغة العربية، للتأكد من الاملاء باللغة العربية`

[image]